# What is the most efficient (fastest) way to level up a character in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm a Charr Engineer, so tips for this class are specifically welcomed.

Comment: @Whoever downvoted: care to explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first character doing heart events, farming every tree, mine, plant you come across and always dropping what you are doing and helping in dynamic events is the fastest way to level.

The greatest xp/time are events so if you can find continuously repeating event chains that is the fastest way to level outside for a first time character.

Comment: You could also spend gems on xp booster items from the gem store. Dynamic events are the best way to get exp whilst exploring imho.

Answer (score 4):

**Crafting.**

Leveling a crafting profession to 400 gives you ~10 levels (this xp is percentage based, so it always gives you 10 levels, regardless of what level you started at).

There are 8 crafting professions, and a the max level is 80, so *if you have the mats*, you can hit 80 from 2 in under an hour.

Comment: So if I'm a new player I only have to farm crafting mats or money to buy crafting mats?

Comment: What? I never played GW2 except 2-3h on Beta Weekends but THIS seems quite abusive O_O

Comment: @F.S. I don't agree. There's nothing to be gained from getting to max level as fast as possible. And you are, perhaps, underestimating the raw volumes of materials required to do so.

Comment: @edem I'd gather mats while doing renown hearts, and craft when you can. It's easy to add crafting in to other leveling methods.

Comment: I did not ask whether I will gain anything or not. I just asked which way is the fastest.

Comment: The absolute fastest way would be to spend money to buy gems to turn into gold and buy the materials needed to grind crafting for the levels, yes.

Comment: @Gwen an even faster (but completely evil) way is to buy gold from the chinese spammers :)  much better rate than the 'official' way

Comment: @Rodolfo You're also liable to get banned.

Comment: @edem It's the fastest way. It's just viable for someone's first character (since they have no money or mats).

Comment: The situation here has changed since ascended crafting was implemented. You no longer get 10 levels from 1-400 crafting, only 8.